# Mysql transactions and triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have to create a certain MySql log table. That table should contain all the changes that happened to the table "A".

In order to do that, i have created a stored procedure "writeLog" that's populating the log table. That procedure is a bit complex and needs exclusive access to few tables so i'm using "start transaction" and "commit" in that procedure. It works.

The problem is that table "A" (the one that should be logged) is being populated from many different parts of the system that's using my db and in order to avoid adding "log" code all over the place i decided to call my "writeLog" stored procedure after each update and insert in the "A". It's important to note that i need to log one format of data after "update", another after "insert" and software that's pushing data to the "A" has no idea if data is being updated or inserted (it's all done, again, using stored procedures that have "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" part).

When i try to perform "call writeLog(....old.data...new.data...)" from the "after update" trigger i get an error that basically says i'm not allowed to have explicit or implicit transactions in trigger.

What should i do? I'm trying to create as simple as possible logging so i'm using the trigger, but again i need to perform transactions because i don't want several different parts of the software to mess with "LogTable" in the same time.

Any idea?